# Sometimes video jumps while presenting it from a third party app on iOS 10

Tags: ios, video, lightning

I am trying to present a video from a third party app on my iPhone 6s (iOS 10) to an extended screen via the [Lightning Digital AV Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD826AM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter). But sometimes it lags/jumps, making the video almost unwatchable.

Why does it do this? How can I stop the video from lagging and jumping?

Comment: What are you presenting to? HDMI output to a projector/screen? Do other machines lag when you plug them into the HDMI the same way (minus the adapter)?

Comment: Hdmi output to a projector screen.

Comment: If you, say, plug a computer in, does it still lag/jump? Do other apps on the iPhone have the lagging and jumping effect or just this specific third-party one?

Comment: need to check. Video jumps only at the end... It has 59 minutes...

Comment: That, to me, sounds like an issue with the app. I need to know more specifics (is it the iPhone, the app, the video, the adapter, the cable, or the projector, we must determine).

Comment: iphone 6S, adapter completely new, cable hdmi completely new...